# PHP Contact form not sending email. Not sure if syntax or Server

Tags: php, html, forms

Hey guys so I have an HTML document with a contact form I created and it is not working. I have the PHP in a seperate PHP file like so:

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="form_process.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label white-color">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label white-color">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="First Name" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label white-color">Message</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Type your message here!" name="message" required></textarea>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg text-center" id="send-btn" name="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is the PHP:

```
<?php

if (isset($POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $to = 'j_goris@live.com';
    $subject = 'JorgeGoris.com Form Submission';
    $text = "Name: ".$name."\n"."Email: ".$email."\n". "Wrote the following: "."\n\n".$message;

    if(mail($to, $subject, $text, "From: ".$name)){
        echo '<h1>Thanks! I will get back to you shortly.</h1>';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Sorry there was an error! Please try again.';
    }
}?>
```

This is my first time tackling PHP contact forms. I uploaded all my files to my server and still no dice. Can you guys see whats wrong?

Comment: Please take care while posting the code snippets. Dont display sensitive information like email ids.

Comment: Alright will do.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace:**

```
$POST['name']
```

**to:**

```
$_POST['name']
```

**Replace:**

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $text, "From: ".$name)){
```

**To:**

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $text, "From: ".$email)){
```

**Full Code:**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $to = 'j_goris@live.com';
    $subject = 'JorgeGoris.com Form Submission';
    $text = "Name: ".$name."\n"."Email: ".$email."\n". "Wrote the following: "."\n\n".$message;

    if(mail($to, $subject, $text, "From: ".$email)){
        echo '<h1>Thanks! I will get back to you shortly.</h1>';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Sorry there was an error! Please try again.';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Wow I didn't even see that underscore was missing! thanks a ton I need to get used to that. However now I am getting the error part of my conditional. I will keep looking for more errors. Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: @Fate I updated the code. You were sending $name in FROM instead of sending $email. Certainly keep an eye on those variables. You almost had it, small errors are part of learning.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I fixed it up however now I am getting the error part of my conditional instead of a success. I am not sure where the conditional is going wrong

Comment: Yup, I know, replace $name in your mail function to $email. Currently mail() is not sending an email, hence it fails. @Fate

Comment: I did I have if(mail($to, $subject, $text, "From: ".$email)){